# GQL Functions and Datastore Datetime query trouble

Tags: datetime, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions, gql

**This is the context:**

*I have a GCP Function that must to go to Datastore to get some data to return an array to client.*

**The Problem:**

*I can't achieve that GCP Functions returns data when I use Datetime filters about my code, however, when I put the equivalent query on GCP Datastore Query console, i can achieve turn back a lot of rows.*

**Technical data:**

> Datastore GQL:

```
select * from KIND where recordDate >= DATETIME ("2018-10-10T10:10:00.000000+03:00") and recordDate <= DATETIME ("2018-10-11T10:10:00.999999+03:00")
```

*(It works on GCP Datastore console)*

> GCP Functions Code:

```
    query = datastore.createQuery(kind).filter('recordDate','>=',dateFrom).filter('recordDate','<=',dateTo);
    console.log(query);

    datastore.runQuery(query, (err,entities) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(entities);
    });
```

*(It runQuery()... always returns null as err variable and returns a void Array on entity variable)*

**The help I need:**

> Can anybody tell me an example of a successful case of a query that
>   returns entities using Datetime filters ?

---

Ways I tried about the format of dateFrom and dateTo vars:

- DATETIME ("2018-10-10T10:10:00.000000+03:00")
- DATETIME ("2018-10-10 10:10:00")
- "2018-10-10T10:10:00.000000+03:00"
- '2018-10-10T10:10:00.000000+03:00'
- DATETIME ("2018-10-10")
- "2018-10-10"
- DATE ("2018-10-10")
- DATE ('2018-10-10')
- DATETIME (2018-10-10T10:10:00.000000+03:00)

And no one works :(

> UPDATE (2018-11-19):

I printed the query before do runQuery and I get this:
(I PUT SOME DOTS TO SAFE SENSIBLE DATA)

```
    {
      "textPayload": "Query {\n  scope: \n   Datastore {\n     clients_: Map {},\n     datastore: [Circular],\n     namespace: undefined,\n     projectId: '................',\n     defaultBaseUrl_: 'datastore.googleapis.com',\n     baseUrl_: 'datastore.googleapis.com',\n     options: \n      { libName: 'gccl',\n        libVersion: '2.0.0',\n        scopes: [Array],\n        servicePath: 'datastore.googleapis.com',\n        port: 443,\n        projectId: 'c..........' },\n     auth: \n      GoogleAuth {\n        checkIsGCE: undefined,\n        jsonContent: null,\n        cachedCredential: null,\n        _cachedProjectId: 'c..........',\n        keyFilename: undefined,\n        scopes: [Array] } },\n  namespace: null,\n  kinds: [ '....KIND......' ],\n  filters: \n   [ { name: 'recordDate', op: '>', val: 2018-10-10T00:00:00.000Z },\n     { name: 'recordDate', op: '<', val: 2018-10-12T23:59:59.000Z } ],\n  orders: [],\n  groupByVal: [],\n  selectVal: [],\n  startVal: null,\n  endVal: null,\n  limitVal: 20,\n  offsetVal: -1 }",
      "insertId": "............................098...",
      "resource": {
        "type": "cloud_function",
        "labels": {
          "region": "us-central1",
          "function_name": "...................-get-search",
          "project_id": "............."
        }
      },
      "timestamp": "2018-11-19T21:19:46.737Z",
      "severity": "INFO",
      "labels": {
        "execution_id": "792s.....lp"
      },
      "logName": "projects/......./logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
      "trace": "projects/........../traces/4a457.......",
      "receiveTimestamp": "2018-11-19T21:19:52.852569373Z"
}
```

> And the Functions Code is:

```
query = datastore.createQuery(kind).filter('recordDate','>',new Date(dateFrom)).filter('recordDate','<',new Date(dateTo)).limit(20);

console.log(query);

var test = datastore.runQuery(query, (err,entities) => {

    console.log(err);
    console.log(entities);

    entities.forEach(entity => {
        console.log(entity);
      });
      return{
          entities:entities,
          err:err
      };
});
console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

When using the client libraries to filter or sort query results based on datetime properties you should use the native datetime representation in the respective language, not strings or the GQL structures.

In particular for node.js which you apparently use you should use `Date()` objects. Here's an example from  [Restrictions on queries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#restrictions_on_queries):

> ```
> const query = datastore
>   .createQuery('Task')
>   .filter('created', '>', new Date('1990-01-01T00:00:00z'))
>   .filter('created', '<', new Date('2000-12-31T23:59:59z'));
> ```

Comment: I tried this way too my friend... when you post this here I tried again because I believe that i am crazy but not... the query do nothing... i can't understand why yet. I question to google people and they response me... I will evaluate this and then I will tell to everybody the correct way to solve this problem. Thanks for your response. :)

Comment: Google staff says yu have the correct way... So i printed the query to can show you more data. Please checkout this (I will update the header)

Comment: It does not work because it returns a void array as response and nothing on error variable. So strange